# reading sk_buff and getting iphdr in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, ip, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to read `sk_buff->network_header` but when I try to read my computer get froze and never gets unfreez. Why is that happening. This is my code in poll of napi api

```
        In probe function
        netif_napi_add(netdev, &adapter->napi, e1000e_poll, 64);            
        

        static int e1000e_poll(struct napi_struct *napi, int budget)
        {
        struct sk_buff *skb=napi->skb;
        // (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(&napi->skb); 
         struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb->network_header;
            struct udphdr *udp_header;
            struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
            struct list_head *p;

            //unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I simply dont want to assign just about anything to something similar. I had check types when assigning plus prinkk not the solution since it does not have formats that covers all types